# Menu lines between each item

Tags: css, menu, space

This is my layouts menu:

http://gyazo.com/da1f1954a34694facaaab8ce6c92b267

Can you see the Black and white low opacity lines between each menu item?
How do I make them exactly in that size? also you can see theres a space amount of space in each menu item, how do I do so?

Thanks

Comment: Without your code no one can tell you what exactly you need to do.

Comment: I have no code, it's just a regular menu using Uls and lists, I just need to know a good way on adding a line image between each menu item

Comment: If you want 100 % Match then slice and use as an image. You 'll have to write some HTML + CSS for this. About alternative, you can use right border of left box as white and left border of right box as black. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) For borders use rgba:

```
your_li_element_selector {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* white border with opacity 50% */
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* black border with opacity 50% */
}
```

Hide left border for the first menu item:

```
your_li_element_selector:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Hide right border for the last menu item:

```
your_li_element_selector:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

2) For space use `margin` and `padding` properties of `li` element and `a` inside it.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do border left and border right using RGBA and change the opacity down. First-child and last-child to remove the extra borders. Downside is the above things will not work in some older browers. As @dev said the best fit might be using images.

Example using RGBA, first-child and last-child: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra9NT/